# Hide section of blogger template on page load based on a string present in the url

Tags: blogger

How can I hide a section in my blogger template (contempo) on page load based on a string present in the url?

In particular I'd like to hide the aside / sidebar-container based on a url parameter that is present, for example `myblog.com/p/mypage.html?sidebar=hide`

Note I'm not looking to use CSS such as `display:none` as that still loads all of the aside content from the template adding to page load time due to unnecessary bulk.  **I'm looking to exclude it from the template section code based on a string contains (or similar) condition**.

For example, I'd love to be able to use something like `<b: if cond=` to exclude a section from the template, BUT in my case I need something like `<b: if cond CONTAINS mystring`  (    the key difference being the use of `CONTAINS` instead of `=`    )

I've been looking for an answer to this for months off and on with no replies on how to do it.

Thank you if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blogger ignore most of url params, so you can't use `?sidebar=hide`.

The only param (I know) that can be a used like that is `view`, because we can get the value using `<data:blog.view/>`.

For example `?view=hide-sidebar`

Then:

```xml
<b:if cond='data:blog.view == "hide-sidebar"'>
  <!-- don't show sidebar -->
</b:if>
```

Comment: Cool, I confirmed this works as a workaround!  (Too bad it only works with a parameter named 'view' rather than any parameter name.)   But this workaround works.   Thank you.